# Retrieve joined data from two tables that has the latest date

Tags: plsql

I need to write a procedure that has output cursor with columns: `source_serial (number), source_readout_type_id (number), source_indicator_id (number), source_read_date_latest (date)`.

source_serial is from HEADERS table, and other columns are from ITEMS table.

For all combinations of columns: `source_serial (number), source_readout_type_id (number), source_indicator_id (number)`, retrieve a combination with latest date.

```
   procedure get_items_latest(o_cur_results out sys_refcursor,
                              result_code out number)
   is
   begin

   result_code:=0;
   open o_cur_results for
   select 
   h.source_serial,
   i.source_readout_type_id,
   i.source_indicator_id
   /*latest date*/

      from log_push_readouts_headers h

      join log_push_readouts_items i
        on /*latest date*/;

                   commit;

                        exception      when others then
        result_code :=9200;
        rollback;
        pkg_common.insert_log_record(p_source => 'get_items_latest',
                p_type => 'Er',
                p_message => sqlerrm);

   end;
```

Could someone show me how to write the "latest date" condition?

Comment: Lookup the MAX() function and GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just write it down.

```
SELECT hdr.source_serial 
      ,its.source_readout_type_id 
      ,its.source_indicator_id 
      ,MAX (its.source_read_date) AS source_read_date_latest
FROM   headers hdr
      ,items   its
GROUP BY hdr.source_serial 
        ,its.source_readout_type_id 
        ,its.source_indicator_id
```

This is a cartesian Join (this is two tables without a join condition) and will return up to count (headers) * count (lines) rows, so up to 1000 billion rows if there are 1.000.000 rows in each table.